# Как создать xlsl для каждого пользователя из запроса sql?

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, list, xlsx

Суть вопроса вот в чем, есть SQL запрос, который возвращает

```
    for i in sql:
     print(i)

    result:
            user1 name1
            user1 name2
            user1 name3
            user2 name1
            user2 name2
            user3 name4
            user3 name5
```

Как мне создать для каждого пользователя ,xls, где будет содержаться строчки для него конкретно.
Типа того:

```
Для user1.xls:
    user1 name1
    user1 name2
    user1 name3

Для user2.xls:
    user2 name1
    user2 name2
```

Как это в цикле обойти и отфильтровать?

Comment: какой тип у result и его содержимого?

Comment: @Jack_oS results_2 = cursor_select.fetchall()  вывод: ('user1', 'name1')('user1', 'name2')('user2', 'name1')

Comment: соберите "вывод" (это список кортежей, насколько я понял) в словарь с ключом по первому элементу и значением - списком вторых элементов, как-то так: `{'user1': ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'], 'user2': ['name1', 'name2'], 'user3': ['name4', 'name5']}`... создавайте файл с именем ключа и в цикле заполняйте значениями второй столбец, а ключем - первый

Comment: @Jack_oS А можете пример кода написать? А то я как раз и не понимаю каК, хотя бы примерно, я дальше накостылю :)

Comment: "не понимаю как"... что конкретно не понимаете? как словарь создать или файл?

Comment: @Jack_oS да как, создать из этого вывода, словарь с ключами и значениями и как заполнять в цикле

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123181/discussion-between-user405396-and-jack-os).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если в ответ на запрос вы получаете список кортежей:

```
sql = [
    ('user1', 'name1'), 
    ('user1', 'name2'), 
    ('user1', 'name3'), 
    ('user2', 'name1'), 
    ('user2', 'name2'), 
    ('user3', 'name4'), 
    ('user3', 'name5')
]
```

то создав на его основе словарь:

```
data = dict()
for s in sql:
    if s[0] in data:
        data[s[0]].append(s[1])
    else:
        data[s[0]] = [s[1]]
```

получите удобную структуру для создания и заполнения файлов:

```
>>> data
{
    'user1': ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'], 
    'user2': ['name1', 'name2'], 
    'user3': ['name4', 'name5']
}
```

Создать файлы можно при помощи библиотеки [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html):

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

for key in data:
    wb = Workbook()
    wb.save(f'{key}.xlsx')
```

теперь у вас в директории, где запускался код, будут три файла: user1.xlsx, user3.xlsx и user3.xlsx, с именами из ключей словаря:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Записать в файл можно в том же цикле обхода словаря data:

```
for i, name in enumerate(data[key], 1):
    ws.cell(row=i, column=1, value=key)
    ws.cell(row=i, column=2, value=name)
```

теперь содержимое user1.xlsx, например, будет таким:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И все вместе:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook


sql = [('user1', 'name1'), ('user1', 'name2'), ('user1', 'name3'), ('user2', 'name1'), ('user2', 'name2'), ('user3', 'name4'), ('user3', 'name5')]
data = dict()

for s in sql:
    if s[0] in data:
        data[s[0]].append(s[1])
    else:
        data[s[0]] = [s[1]]

for key in data:
    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.active
    for i, name in enumerate(data[key], 1):
        ws.cell(row=i, column=1, value=key)
        ws.cell(row=i, column=2, value=name)
    wb.save(f'{key}.xlsx')
```